# vim: Use insert-mode-like completion for command completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Is it possible to use a vertical command line completion just the way it appears when using CTRL-N in insert mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally like

```
set wildmode=longest,list
```

It behaves sort of like bash completion. (It also shows the same information as `<c-d>` when you hit `<tab>`).

Answer (score 2):

You can have such a menu when doing completion in the command-line window (`q:`) but you can't have it in the command-line itself.

But `set wildmenu` (see also `:help wildmode`) is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: I find it much harder to check all the matches when they are listed side by side rather than above each other. :-/

Comment: `<c-d>` might interest you